# Problems in understanding multiple integrals theory.

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, volume

I'm studying Double and Triple Integrals and stucked understanding how to determinate which reduction formula is ok for my case. Also got problems in finding $\rho$ and $\theta$ while switching in polar coordinates. Tried to solve this :

- Calculate the volume |A|, with A = {$x$ $\in$ $\mathfrak R^3$ : $z$ $\ge$ $x^2+$ $y^2$, $z \le 1$, $x\ge z$}

By setting $y = 0$, I drew in $z$ and $x$ axes functions to know which region to look and :

[Region is under green line $z=x$ and above $z=x^2$ in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXVbI.png)

Then :

$$\iiint_A dxdydz = \iint_Ddxdy\int_{x^2+y^2}^xdz  = \iint_D(x-x^2-y^2)dxdy$$

To determinate $D$ i'm setting     $x = x^2 + y^2$ who, by manipulation, is $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 +$ $y^2$ = $\frac{1}{4}$ 
So a circle with center = $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and radius = $\frac{1}{2}$

Now by setting polar coordinates I end up with $0 \le\rho\le cos\theta$ and $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{4}$.

My final answer to this is $\frac{8+3\pi}{384}$. Result is different and it's $\frac{3\pi}{128}$.

I need a comparison just to know if I'm doing this thing in a right way.

Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: The result is, indeed, ${\pi \over 32} = {\color{#f00}{4}\pi \over 128}$. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Here after, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is an
>   [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

As you can see, the region '$x > 1$' has empty intersection with '$x^{2} + y^{2} < z < 1$'. So, your integration is solely over a region with '$x < 1$' and '$x^{2} + y^{2} < z < x$'.

\begin{align}
\iiint_{A}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z & =
\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} \leq z \leq \min\braces{1,x}}
\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[1cm] & =
\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{x \leq 1}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} \leq z \leq x}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & +
\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{x \geq 1}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} \leq z \leq 1}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[1cm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{1}\bracks{x^{2}  + y^{2} \leq x}
\int_{x^{2} + y^{2}}^{x}\dd z\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\ & +
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}
\bracks{x^{2}  + y^{2} \leq 1}
\int_{x^{2} + y^{2}}^{1}\dd z\,\dd x\,\dd y}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
\\[1cm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{1/2}
\bracks{x^{2}  + y^{2} \leq {1 \over 4}}
\int_{x^{2} + x + 1/4 + y^{2}}^{x + 1/2}\dd z\,\dd x\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1/2}\pars{{1 \over 4} - r^{2}}r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{\pi \over 32}}
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciated your solution. Thanks for it.

Comment: @RobertoPavia I'm glad it was useful at all. Thanks.